# HttpClient returns json once and then returns undefined

Tags: json, angular, angular-httpclient

I am reading the contents of a JSON from a server using `HttpClient`. I am able to read the contents once successfully but when I read it a second time it always returns `undefined`.

This is what my `.ts` looks like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private httpService: HttpClient) { }

  getData() {
    this.httpService.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LearnWebCode/json-example/master/animals-1.json').subscribe(
          result => { 
            console.log(result)
          }
    )
  }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.getData()
     setInterval(this.getData, 10000)
   }
}
```

`HttpClient` is imported into `app.module.ts` correctly as the first time I read the JSON it works without a problem.

Here is a [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-au46gv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) with the issue.

I am using `setInterval` because I want to be able to keep reading the JSON as the values will update. Am I meant to be closing the `httpClient.get` request so that I can make another.

I have seen other questions where the request always returns `undefined` but mine only returns `undefined` on and after the second request.

How do I successfully get the contents of the JSON each time I send the get request?

**EDIT**
Apparently for some my stackblitz works not a problem, here is a screenshot from the stackblitz of the console with the issue:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is setInterval in an Angular service only firing one time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43908009/why-is-setinterval-in-an-angular-service-only-firing-one-time)

Comment: @Dino Not a duplicate as the `setinterval` is firing correctly. Please have a look at the linked StackBlitz before flagging.

Comment: Your stackblitz works fine, and yes this is a duplicate. The answers you got are the same ones as in that post I referenced. Please check it again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**this** in the function given to setInterval doesn't point to the class when it is called.

Use arrow function instead.

```js
    setInterval(() => { this.getData(); }, 10000);
```

Comment: In stackblitz I do not get the error anymore after refreshing the preview page.  It seems like the process is still running in the background even after changing the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have used `this.getData`, it should be `this.getData()`
and you have to use an arrow function.

Try this:

```
setInterval(() => this.getData(), 10000);
```

Comment: I still get: `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` occasionally. Why would this be? I have increased the interval and still get this?

Answer (score 0):

Use of arrow function is a great response but you should be careful when using `setInterval`. 
You should definitely prefer usage of RxJS in an Angular application context :

```
interval(10000).pipe(
   mergeMap(() => this.getData())
).subscribe()
```

Bad practices usage of setInterval : https://dev.to/akanksha_9560/why-not-to-use-setinterval--2na9